# Discord Bot that check proxies gives a funny error

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, discord, discord.js

It keeps returning these errors. I've checked if it was my proxy API - but its not. I believe its an internal error. I've double checked and NPM installed all the dependencies. Still returns this error.
Again, all help is appreciated. Thanks for your time :3

```
(node:28544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at Message.delete (c::user/example/\Message.js:500:44)        
    at c:user/example/server.js:27:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:28544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28544) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:28544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at Message.delete (c::user/example/\Message.js:500:44)
    at c:\Users\aweso\Downloads\polarcop_discord-master\server.js:32:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:28544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: You need to show the code that's causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on stack trace you provided, you are passing invalid parameter to `message.delete()` method. On v12 it takes an object with `timeout` and/or `reason` keys, like shown in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete). For example, instead of `delete(1000)` you have to do `delete({ timeout: 1000 })`

Note however, that not everyone would be able to answer that question without providing more information, like code that gives you that error.

Comment: @Tanku Looking into your code, only thing i can say is that what i said in the answer is correct. Lines 27, 32, 50 and 55 are exactly what i mentioned.

Comment: fixed it. Still doesn't return back the proxy. Its blank.

Comment: Even if, fixing/debugging rest of your code is out of the scope of your original question. Consider marking this answer as accepted and asking new one instead.